# How to stop the right div wrapping below the left div

Tags: css, html, positioning, word-wrap

I am having a problem with a div wrapping underneath the left div it is side by side with, I want the div to get narrower until it is side by side with the menubar, and then stop moving but not wrap.

I have two divs side by side, the div on the left is a menu bar, and the one on the right is a div used to enter content on the site. The div on the left is set to take 16% of the width, and the one on the right is set to take 86% of the width. When I make the browser window narrower it resizes getting more narrow, until the mainpage div wraps underneath the menubar div. I want to stop the div wrapping underneath.

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<title>rthrhtdrhrth</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style30 {
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: left;
}
.auto-style32 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!--In this site the design code is the same for each page such as the menubar, and banners however the mainpage content will be
different for each page as it contains that pages individual content. 

<!--The below bannerdiv div, is the div that contains the top banner picture for the sight. 
percentages are used throughout the site to maintain a liquid layout. -->
<div id="bannerdiv" align="left" title="Banner">
    <img alt="z" height="114" src="Untitled3.jpg" width="100%"></div>
<div id="container">
    <h3 id="container" class="auto-style4">ythtytytyytht</h3>
    <!--The container div is used to create top green line. --></div>
<div id="menubar" align="center" style="width: 16%; height: 100px;" title="menu">
    <!-- This is the code for the menubar, to add a new option to the menubar-->
    <!-- Add a new <li> tag below the bottom link, to delete a link, delete the desired
                                                                                    link element. -->
    <ul>
        <li style="">
        <img alt="logo" height="63" src="images/ClevelandLogo.gif" width="126"></li>
        <li><a auto-style5"="" href="index.html" style="height: 20px;  class=">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="general.html">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="map.html">Site map</a></li>
        <li><a href="rules.html">Rules &amp; Procdures</a></li>
        <li><a href="enviro.html" style="height: 20px">Envirommental</a></li>
        <li><a href="energy.html">Energy</a></li>
        <li><a href="it.html">IT</a></li>
        <li><a href="sap.html">SAP</a></li>
        <li><a href="purchasing.html" style="height: 20px; width: 180px;">Purchasing</a></li>
        <li><a href="quality.html">Quality</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>
        <li><a href="hr.html">Human resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
        <li><a href="eng.html">Engineering</a></li>
        <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="tees.html">Teesdock</a></li>
        <li><a href="cmp.html">Company mobile phones</a></li>
        <li><a href="cms.html">Climate Survery Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.html">Sports Dome</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--The mainpage div is where all the page's indivdual content is displayed.-->
<div id="mainpage" class="auto-style1" style="height: 486px; width: 84%; float: right; color: #000000; font-size: 11pt;">
</div>
<!-- The container1 div is used to create the bottom green line in the site -->
</div>
<h3 id="container1" class="auto-style4" style="width: 100%"></h3>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Picturecontainer2 contains the image that creates the bottom site banner. -->
<div id="picturecontainer2" style="float: left;">
    <img alt="z" height="114" src="da.png" width="100%"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #008852;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 10%;
}
#main
{
overflow-x:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    weight: 100&;
}
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;

}

#picturecontainer1{
    float: left;
}
#menubar

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px
}
#menubar a:link, #menubar a:visited
{
    border-top-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #EFF1EB;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #638529;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px;
    position: fixed;
}
#mainpage {
    border: thin solid #008852;
    width: 84%;
    float: none;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    color: #008852;
    clear: none;

}
#menubar a:hover, #menubar a:active
{
    background-color: #7A991A;
}
#menubar {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: xx-small;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 11px;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: 0%;
}
#bannerdiv 
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

.newStyle1 {
    text-align: left;
}
footer {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #008852;
}
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
s
#bannerdiv {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style4 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.auto-style5 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.auto-style8 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: xx-small;
}
.auto-style6 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: xx-small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.auto-style10 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.auto-style12 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: xx-small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style11 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style9 {
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium";
    position: fixed;
}
#container1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #008852;
    clear: right;
}

#table {
}
#mainpage a:link, #mainpage a:visited {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: static;
    clear: none;
      display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    clear: both; 

}
#picturecontainer1 {
    border-style: none;
    width: 126px;
    border-right-width: thick;
    border-bottom-width: thick;
    border-left-width: thick;
}
.auto-style20 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style21 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
}
.auto-style19 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style17 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style15 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.auto-style18 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#mainpage a:link, #mainpage a:visited {
}
.auto-style23 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    a text-decoration: none; 


}
.auto-style14 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#picturecontainer2 img, #bannerdiv img {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.auto-style21 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.auto-style14 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style15 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainpage a:hover a: active {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style25 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style26 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style38 {
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style27 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style24 {
    text-align: center;
}
p, h2, h3, h4, td, a  {
    color: #008852;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style14 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.auto-style15 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.auto-style17 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style18 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
.auto-style19 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.auto-style20 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style21 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#query {
    height: 200px;
}
.auto-style30 {
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: left;
}
.auto-style32 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}
.auto-style14 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.auto-style15 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.auto-style17 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style18 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
.auto-style19 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
}
#picturecontainer2 {
    border-style: none;
    float: left;
}
#wrapper {
min-width:100%
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to post for what seems like a simple layout question. Can you strip things down to the bare minimum required to reproduce your problem? You can then create a jsFiddle based on that simplified code; you may even find the answer yourself in the process.

Comment: I agree with @Lorax here.  Could you please create a fiddle and provide the link here with the stripped down version that shows what issue you're trying to solve? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Start with removing the `position:fixed` you have on `#mainpage` and see how that helps you. You do have a lot of style going on, and that makes it hard to troubleshoot. You should first get your positioning set and then add the pretty stuff once you have it laid out right (IMHO).